# Coverage not finding tests

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, tox, coverage.py

Coverage doesn't seem to be picking up the "coverage" of the tests in the directory `tests`. The source files are in a directory `src`. (File names have been changed to protect the innocent.)

Here is the tox.ini:

```
[tox]
envlist = py3


[testenv]
extras = test
commands =
    pip list --format=columns
    coverage run --rcfile=.coveragerc -m pytest --full-trace -l --strict -v
    coverage combine --append
    coverage report -im
    coverage html -i
exclude =
    .tox,
    .git,
    __pycache__,
    'src/reports',
    'src/target_files',
    test,
    venv


[flake8]
exclude =
    .tox,
    .git,
    __pycache__,
    'src/reports',
    'src/target_files',
    test,
    venv
max-line-length = 111
```

Here is the coveragerc:

```
[run]
branch=True
context=src
omit = test
source=
    src
timid=True
parallel=True
[report]
omit=
    .tox/*
```

Here is the setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools import find_packages

_INSTALL_REQUIRES = [
    "pytest"
]
_EXTRAS_REQUIRE = {
  "test": [
    "flake8",
    "coverage",
    "mock",
    "setuptools"
  ]
}

setup(
    author='...',
    author_email='...',
    description='',
    extras_require=_EXTRAS_REQUIRE,
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=_INSTALL_REQUIRES,
    license='',
    name='...',
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    packages=find_packages(where="src"),
    url='',
    version='1'
)
```

This outputs:

```
Coverage.py warning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected)
py3 run-test: commands[2] | coverage combine --append
py3 run-test: commands[3] | coverage report -im
Name                               Stmts   Miss Branch BrPart  Cover   Missing
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
src/__init__.py                        0      0      0      0   100%
src/[file].py                          7      7      0      0     0%   1- 13
src/[file].py                         13     13      0      0     0%   1-18
src/lib/__init__.py                    0      0      0      0   100%
src/lib/[file].py                     83     83     26      0     0%   1-161
src/lib/[file].py                     49     49     16      0     0%   1-67
src/lib/[file].py                     92     92     22      0     0%   1-117
src/lib/[file].py                     47     47     20      0     0%   1-71
src/lib/[file].py                     34     34      8      0     0%   1-42
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                325    325     92      0     0%
```

There are tests for each of the files in this list. What can I do to get coverage to notice them?

Answer (score 2):

There is no python package named `src` in your environment. It should match the name of your package (which you've replaced with ...).

```
[run]
# Change this to your package name. 
source=
    src
```

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you add an `__init__.py` file to the tests folder. That should be enough for coverage to pick them up.